How to strip the digit from a string
I am trying to extract a number from a string using regex for javascript.
Test cases
value[0]        ---> 0
value[1]        ---> 1
object2value[0] ---> 0
object90        ---> no match

i tried using ([\w]+)*?\[\d\] but it give
value[0]        ---> value[0]
value[1]        ---> value[1]
object2value[0] ---> object2value[0]
object90        ---> no match

how i can achieve this.

Put \d in a capture group and then use match[2] to get that capture group's match.

Can the number be more than 9? Then use \d+

([\w]+)*? can be simplified to just \w*. And since it can match an empty string, you can omit it from the regexp entirely. You just need to match a digit inside [].

Couldn't \b\d+\b be enough though?

Use lookbehind and lookahead assertions:


const tests = `value[0]       
value[1]       
object2value[0]
object90`.match(/\S+/g);

const regex = /(?<=\w+\[)\d+(?=\])/;

tests.forEach(t => console.log(t, '=>', ...t.match(regex) ?? ['no match']));



To extract the both var name and number:


const tests = `value[0]       
value[1]       
object2value[0]
object90`.match(/\S+/g);

const regex = /(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/;

tests.forEach(t => {
  const [, value, num] = t.match(regex) ?? [, 'no match', 'no match'];
  console.log(t, '=>', value, ':', num);
});




Thank you. Can you also help me with extracting the string part. e.g value[0] becomes value and value[1].id becomes value

A Gilani, this regular expression matches "%[8]&$@#0[9]", with "9" the returned match and "0" saved to capture group 1. Is that OK? If you simply want to return the digits surrounded by brackets, and don't need to check what comes before, just match (<=\[)\d+(?=\d) or \[(d+)\]. If there is a match the digits of interest will be given by the match in the first case and will be held in capture group 1 in the second.
